# How to fast replace the keyword instead of recreating a string

Tags: c++

I have a big fixed-format string, and I need to reuse it a lot of times, each time, it just needs to revise some keywords, then keep the left the same.

```cpp
double qty = 1.;
double price = 123123.;
char body[256];
snprintf(body, sizeof(body), "{\"productType\": \"usdt-futures\", \"marginMode\": \"crossed\", 
  \"orderType\": \"limit\", \"marginCoin\": \"USDT\", \"size\":\"%s\", \"price\":\"%s\",
     \"force\": \"ioc\", \"clientOid\": \"%s\", \"side\": \"%s\", \"symbol\": \"%s\"}",
       std::to_string(qty).c_str(), std::to_string(price).c_str(), "asdasdas", 
         (qty > 0 ? "buy" : "sell"), "BTC_USDT");
```

As above shows, each time, I just need to replace four keyword: `price`, `qty`, `clientOid` and `side`.

The fixed part is huge, I just listed some.

So, if I `snprintf` every time, it will cost about 90us, which is too expensive for me.

How do I just reuse the string buffer, and replace the keyword each time, to reduce the latency?

Comment: It looks like you're creating a JSON-like structure. Why not use a proper JSON library?

Comment: Have you tried [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format)?

Comment: Also, why do you assume there's a "fast way"? Sometimes you just have to go through the motions and do the work.

Comment: Have you profiled your program and verified this is actually a bottleneck?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, it's a json object, but i need the json string as my purpose, i test the rapidjson revise the value, but it is slower than just snprintf a new long string, i think it because the serialize is time costly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl becuase i think there is some waste to create a new string, as those string are 90% same, only 10% keywork different, the recreate of same part is a waste.

Comment: @StephenNewell yes, i am very sensitive about latency, 100us and 10us make a solid different for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking how to do something in C++ but your code is more C than C++. You don't use `stringstream`, `<<` operator, and apart from `std::string` I don't see any objects, just a bunch of variables and a fixed size `char` buffer.

If your JSON key order is not fixed (and it shouldn't be unless the parser is as bad as the generator), then you should put all the keys that are static at the beginning of the buffer, and just append the 4 keys that always change to the end of it.

Something like this:

```
// prepare the fixed part of the buffer
char const * const Fixed = "{ \"longjson\": \"goeshere\", \"and\": \"itspreformatted\", ";
char Buffer[256];
strcpy(Buffer, Fixed);
int AppendPos = strlen(Buffer) + 1;
// repeat the part below as many times as you need
snprintf(&Buffer[AppendPos], _countof(Buffer) - AppendPos - 1, "\"qty\": %d, \"price\": %.2f }", qty, price);
```

**NOTE**

This code is untested and may have errors, it's meant just as an explainer. I would strongly advise you to start using RapidJSON — [here is a nice tutorial](https://gotask.net/programming/serialize-and-deserialize-object-in-cpp-using-rapidjson/) on how to properly serialize C++ objects to JSON:

Sample code from the tutorial is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/eyalmolad/gotask/tree/master/C%2B%2B/RapidJSONSample).